# method selectmenu() does not exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can you help me with this code :

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#roomresults').append('<option value="ahoj">say hallo</option>');
            $('#roomresults').selectmenu('refresh'); 
            });
```

and my select :

```
<label for="roomresults"> Results: </label>
<select name="roomresults" id="roomresults" data-theme="c">
</select>
```

it looks simply, but when i run it, my javascript console tell me

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectmenu'

where is the problem? thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Everything is in the error message, what are you trying to do?

Comment: ok what is selectmenu() ???? :)

Comment: No problem with the code for me. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQv4D/)

Comment: selectmenu('refresh') is used to restyle select box in jQuery Mobile.

Comment: i am trying to refresh selectmenu with new option after page is loaded...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/2wmZK/ example from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use this syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#roomresults').append('<option value="ahoj">say hallo</option>');
    $('#roomresults').selectmenu('refresh'); 
});
```

Use it like this:

```
$(document).live('pageinit',function(e,data){
    $('#roomresults').append('<option value="ahoj">say hallo</option>');
    $('#roomresults').selectmenu('refresh'); 
});
```

Reason: **$(document).ready(function() {** is not enough, at this point jQuery mobile is starting to load pages into the DOM. Event ***pageinit*** is used to check if jQM is successfully loaded. Only after or during this event you can used jQM functionality like ***selectmenu('refresh')***.

You can find more about that here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

And what is an answer without the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/2wmZK/

Comment: next time i will read documentation properly .. :) Actually, i have no error message, but selectmenu is still not updated (i tried your code).Probably i have some stupid error..or i have no idea. Thanks for your answer